# TCL I want to find a regex pattern to match only integers

Tags: javascript, regex, tcl, regex-lookarounds

I am using

```
(?<![\d.])[0-9]+(?![\d.])
```

This does the job for me but I can't use it as it says **"couldn't compile regular expression pattern: quantifier operand invalid while executing"**

I'm looking for any equivalents.

Comment: Can you provide some examples of input and output?

Comment: this regex (?<![\d.])[0-9]+(?![\d.]) uses lookbehind  and tcl doesn't know about this it gives an error so I'm trying to find another pattern that gives me the same result of matching only the integers out of a string.

Comment: Why is this tagged JavaScript if you're using tcl?

Comment: Why not simply use `^\d+$` if you want to match integers (string comprising only digits)?

Comment: it'll match fractions of floats

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tcl regex does not support lookbehinds, although it supports lookaheads.

You can use something like

```
set data {12  3.45 1.665 345}
set RE {(?:^|[^0-9.])(\d+)(?!\.?\d)}
set matches [regexp -all -inline -- $RE $data]
foreach {- group1} $matches {
   puts "$group1"
}
```

Output:

```
12
345
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/2qz3TB). The `(?:^|[^0-9.])(\d+)(?!\.?\d)` regex matches

- `(?:^|[^0-9.])` - start of string or a char other than a digit and a dot
- `(\d+)` - Group 1: one or more digits
- `(?!\.?\d)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is an optional `.` and then a digit immediately to the right of the current location.

Answer (score 0):

If the integers are individual words and not framed by other characters, you don't need a regular expression to get just them and prune out the non-ints:

```
% set data {12  3.45 1.665 345}
12  3.45 1.665 345
% set ints [lmap w $data { if {[string is integer $w]} { set w } else { continue } }]
12 345
```

or just `string is integer $whatever` if you want to check to see if a variable contains just an integer. There's also `wideint` for 64-bit integers and `entier` for bigints.

Answer (score 0):

Picking up the comment

> Why not simply use `^\d+$` if you want to match integers (string comprising only digits)?

Based on the response of the OP and the (accepted) answer, the problem comes from applying text manipulation to (the string representation of) a list. One possible solution in that case is `lsearch`:

```
% set data {12  3.45 1.665 345}
12  3.45 1.665 345
% lsearch -all -regexp -inline $data {^\d+$}
12 345
```